# Kafka transactions with exception

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I have a situation in which Producer A writes on topics A,B and C however listener for topic C throws an exception. All writes are part of a transaction. I want to know if there is a way that all writes can be rolled back automatically, as if no there were no commits in the first place?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved in Kafka out of the box. I would suggest to re-think the design since Kafka/ messaging system is not the best match for your requirement. Kafka consumers are meant to be independent business logic like a micro-service, even if one fails it should not affect the other. If its so critical you may consider a single topic/webservice with all required info in that topic/request and make the client transactional. Otherwise if non-critical(failure of a topic client is not affecting functionality of another topic client), then introduce some audit/alerting mechanism on top of clients to make sure that they are back online.